# Remove all model derived properties?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have loaded custom properties into the Autodesk Forge viewer using the CustomPropertyExtension, which can be found at:

https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-extensions/tree/master/public/extensions/CustomPropertiesExtension

But now I want to remove all properties that are included in the 3D model before adding my own properties.
How do I modify the extension so that I'm able to do that?

My guess is that I would have to do something in the setAggregatedProperties before I add custom properties.

```
setAggregatedProperties(propertySet) {
        Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.ViewerPropertyPanel.prototype.setAggregatedProperties.call(this, propertySet);
        // add your custom properties here
        const dbids = propertySet.getDbIds();
        dbids.forEach(id => {
            var propsForObject = this.properties[id.toString()];
            if (propsForObject) {
                for (const groupName in propsForObject) {
                    const group = propsForObject[groupName];
                    for (const propName in group) {
                        const prop = group[propName];
                        console.log("check0 propName, prop, groupName",propName, prop, groupName)
                        this.addProperty(propName, prop, groupName);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a method for that.

Ref: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/propertypanel/#removeallproperties

Comment: Thank you.
Have I been operating on a wrong assumption when I thought that you should only look at the latest version(v7 now)? 
The v7 documentation for property panel doesn't mention any methods:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/UI/PropertyPanel/